# Not able to Post attachments in Yammer via "Post to this group by email" Option

Tags: yammer

I have created one dotnet job (windows service) that use to fetch users date of joining and birthday from PeopleSoft and use to send an email to Yammer group with birthday or Service Award wishes automatically. It is working absolutely fine but whenever we tried to add images like ballon images, cake images etc on email it never posted in Yammer.

Can't we send any image with text on Yammer group?

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks & Regards!!

Comment: Use more relevant tags.

Comment: Thanks Orion for suggestion. I am new to this system. Please help me in correctly tagging my question. Since it is related to yammer that's why I have tagged it as "Yammer"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post attachments via email. You will need to programmatically upload the file to Yammer and then programmatically post to the group and reference the file that you uploaded.

Look at the Yammer REST API at https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/ for more information on how you can accomplish file uploads and posting by API. Specifically, you will need to look at https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-messages.